# C# Windows Service where to save settings Properties.Setting

Tags: c#

I am developing a Windows Service that submits some data to a web api. As Part of this I need to submit a GUID that I am generating with

```
Guid.NewGuid():
```

This GUID would be individual per machine, never change, and be the same for all users who log in. I'm struggling with where to actually store this though. I came across the Properties.Setting which seemed perfect, but if I scope to Application instead of User, it won't let me set the property as it is read only.

How and where do I store the GUID? It will only generate once (when the service starts on a PC for the first time).

Comment: If it were me, I would store data like this for a service in the registry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, you can use the [ConfigurationManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to access and write the GUID in your application setting. From the link above example:

```
static void AddUpdateAppSettings(string key, string value)
{
    try
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
        if (settings[key] == null)
        {
            settings.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            settings[key].Value = value;
        }
        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
    }
    catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings");
    }
}
```

you can use it like:

```
AddUpdateAppSettings("MachineGuid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Works fine!